# Reference a range of cells on all sheets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel, `=$J:$J` references an entire column on the current sheet while `='Sheet2'!$J:$J` references that entire column on `Sheet2` explicitly.

Is there a way to reference column `J` on all sheets without manually typing all the sheet names?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try using [3D cell references](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-HP010102346.aspx).

1. Select the cell in which you'd like to place the reference. Type `=`.
2. While holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, click the first sheet and then click the last sheet.
3. Select the column that you want to reference. You'll end up with something like this:

   `='Sheet1:Sheet3'!J:J`

For example, if you want to sum the contents of column **J** on all three sheets you can use the formula:

```
=SUM('Sheet1:Sheet3'!J:J)
```

#### Creating a Name for your 3D Reference

This will make it easier for you to reference the columns.

1. Go to **Formulas** > **Defined Names**
2. Type your preferred name. In the example below, I used "myrange".
3. Delete the contents of the **Refers to** box and type `=`.
4. While holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, click the first sheet that you want to reference, and then click the last sheet.
5. Select the column that you want to reference. In your case, column **J**. You'll get something like this:

[image]

To sum the contents of column **J** in `Sheet1` through `Sheet3`, you just have to use this formula:

```
=SUM(myrange)
```

Not all Excel formulas can accept 3D references. Here are the ones that do: `SUM`, `AVERAGE`, `AVERAGEA`, `COUNT`, `COUNTA`, `MAX`, `MAXA`,  `MIN`, `MINA`,  `PRODUCT`, `STDEV`, `STDEVA`, `STDEVP`, `STDEVPA`, `VAR`, `VARA`, `VARP`, `VARPA`

Comment: This answers the question (so +1) but it might be wise to caution about summing many whole columns at once. At least put a sensible range in such as 'Sheet1:Sheet3'!$J$1:$J$9999 or a suitably high number without including 1 million rows unecessarily

Comment: @AdamV I agree with you. Though the OP stated he wanted to call on the entire column, it's good practice to avoid doing so.

Comment: This answers my question. However, I am using the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager and it won't accept a 3D range and therefore does not solve my problem. But that's not your fault, so answer accepted.

Comment: Conditional formatting: Make the complex formula evaluate (e.g. =true) into a "hidden" (intermediate) cell, then do the formatting based on that cell.

Comment: @Hannu You can even put the formula into a named range.  Calling that from th CF will do the same without wasting a cell.